# Multiple CSS classes on elements or huge CSS files

Tags: html, css, less

Which of this solutions is better in huge web apps?

**Option A:**

1. Lots of global classes(like .clearfix, .ellipsis etc)
2. Multiple classes per element

result: div with 3 classes: single-post clearfix ellipsis

**Option B:**

1. Lots of global classes(like .clearfix, .ellipsis etc)
2. Using **less** to put them inside specific element like:

   .single-post{
    padding: 5px;
    .clearfix;
    .ellipsis;
   }

html result:

```
<div class="single-post"></div>
```

css result:
repeated css(huge css files)

Which is better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Or Option C

1. Lots of global classes(like .clearfix, .ellipsis etc)
2. Using **less** to associate other classes to the global classes by extending

**LESS**

```
.single-post { 
  padding: 5px; 
  &:extend(.clearfix); 
  &:extend(.ellipsis); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="single-post"></div>
```

**CSS**

Result is repeated css *selectors*, but far smaller css files without repeated *properties* from the global selectors.

```
.clearfix,
.single-post {
  /* clearfix properties */
}

.ellipsis,
.single-post {
  /* ellipsis properties */
}

.single-post {
  /* single-post only properties */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

personally I go with option A, then it's all being run through the DOM and the CSS file doesn't have to jump all over the place grabbing classes and such.

Answer (score 0):

Option A , you could also use LESS to generate a css file for option A. I like to follow the " Don't repeat yourself" principle. Option A is also a lot like how bootstrap works , and inheritance is good practice either way. It saves you quite a lot of work and css code if you set it up like this :

css:

```
.animal{float: left; border: 1px solid black; min-height: 100px; min-width: 100px; border-radius: 5px;}

.cow{background: black; color: white;}
.lion{background: white; color: orange;}
```

html:

```
<div class="animal cow "></div>
<div class="animal lion "></div>
```